# Adjusting single image texture within a material

Tags: uv

I have a knife block that I created and I want to emboss a logo on the face using a normal map and roughness map. The wood texture, though, is already placed on the model in a way that I really like, so adjusting the UV mapping is not an option.

I duplicated the material, and assigned it to a square on the face of the block and was looking at adding an additional normal map and roughness map in the material then scale or transform it into place. I couldn’t figure this out.

Any thoughts on how to include this logo on to the existing model and map?

[image]

Comment: You can create different UV maps and let different textures use one or the other.

Comment: How do you mean? I tried to scale the map and it modified all images connected. I couldn’t figure out how to scale the image texture into the UV.

Comment: I'm always quite slow in writing answers and making screenshots, so I fear before I've finished this someone has come up with an answer  :D  But I can try it.

Answer (score 3):

You can create more UV maps and assign different textures to them to mix them together in a material. In my example I have created a simple Color Grid image mapped onto the default UV map. Now I want to overlay a logo.

[image: default map]

To create a second UV map, hit the Plus button next to the UV slots in the Object Data Properties. By default, the new UV layout will be copied from the first, but you can change it. I've renamed it to UVMap.Logo and placed it on my logo image so that it shows on the front face. To do that, you select the new map in the UV Map node and the logo image in the Image Texture node. I've set the extrapolation to "Extend" so that the logo isn't repeated.

[image: logo map]

Now I'm mixing both maps and images together. Since the logo has a transparent background I'm using the Alpha channel as mix factor. And to give the logo some bump as if it was placed onto the surface, I also use the Alpha channel for the Bump node. And that's it.

[image: uv mix]

Comment: I will take a look and let you know. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @j3d Please do not use the answer section to thank someone, this is for answers to the question only and will be deleted anyway. Instead consider accepting the answer and maybe read here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)